# Why are linked lists almost always used with separate chaining?

Tags: data-structures, vector, hashtable, linked-list

It seems as though every time I see a mention of separate chaining in a hash table, a linked list is used as the data structure to store items with collisions.  Why is this?  For instance, why couldn't you use a vector/array data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a vector of objects, then copying the objects can be expensive so most general purpose hash tables use linked lists, which don't require a copy on deletion or insertion. However, deletion from a hash table is actually rather a rare operation in most code, and insertion should be rare (you don't want to grow long chains) so whenever I've implemented hashes myself I've always used vectors for the chains, with absolutely no problems.

The alternative explanation is that the linked list is the container that people reach for blindly - see my blog comments [here](http://punchlet.wordpress.com/) for more opinion on this.

Comment: Could you point me towards which blog post you're talking about specifically?  I'd be interested to hear more on this.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an vector / ArrayList but:

- You don't need any of the features an ArrayList provides that a linked list doesn't have, such as indexing into the list in O(1) time.
- ArrayLists tend to have a capacity greater than their current length, which wastes memory.
- ArrayLists need to increase their capacity occasionally which is slow.

Comment: Playing the devils advocate: a) You don't need the ability to insert into the list. b) Pointers need to be updated on inserting elements, which is slow. c) Due to overhead from pointers, Linked Lists are always larger than an array list of the same size, which wastes memory.

Comment: b) You only have to update one or two pointers when updating a linked list. When updating an arraylist you have to update a pointer and a count, so there's no real saving here. c) This is only true if there is no extra capacity in the array list, and even then it still isn't true for lists with one element.

Comment: @MarkByers Hello mark, here i have a question.we'd better let the load factor to be 1, but in such way, every LinkedList in hashtable can only contains just one element.I know the purpose of every LinkedList is to solve the collision problem, but i can not understand why need to rehash such table while current element size larger than the original table size? why we can not store more element in every LinkedList?thank you if you can help me out!